# Typescript is not getting installed

Tags: typescript, ubuntu, npm, installation, npm-install

```
npm install -g typescript
```

I tried the above command but I am receiving the following error.

```
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript'
npm ERR!  \[Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript'\] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.
```

Can someone please let me know what I can do to get it installed ?

Comment: https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally

Comment: Did you try doing the things _suggested in the error message_?

Answer (score 1):

As the error message states, `npm` doesn't have permission to create the package directory for installing `typescript`. To amend this, run with the `sudo` command:

`sudo npm install -g typescript`

Enter your password if prompted, and it should install without issue.